# MembershipUser class - Comments method doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, membership

I'm unable to set the `Comments` property of a `MembershipUser` object.

For example:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);                        
mu.Comment = "someComments";
```

I'd expect this to set the `Comment` property of `mu` object to "someComments" and write changes to the database.

Later, I do the following check:

```
mu.Comment == "someComments";
```

`Comment` property is set to null. Is there anything that I need to change in a web.config or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `Membership.UpdateUser(mu)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not too familiar with Membership, but I would assume that you would need to actually save the changes, by calling [`Membership.UpdateUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser.aspx):

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);                         
mu.Comment = "someComments"; 
Membership.UpdateUser(mu);
```